# [vn200.launch] is neither a launch file in package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I got vectornav vn200, and I have followed exactly this tutorial : https://github.com/dawonn/vectornav
When I write "roslaunch vectornav vn200.launch", I get an error:

```
[vn200.launch] is neither a launch file in package [vectornav] nor is [vectornav] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I don't really know why I get such an error ( I am totally beginner with Linux, ROS, and VectorNav ^^ ).

But, when I go to the following directory `~/catkin_ws/src/vectornav/launch`
and I write the comman again `roslaunch vn200.launch` I get the following

```
... logging to /home/quuser/.ros/log/3dbda9a8-740b-11e6-9178-6c88140d9b00/roslaunch-quuser-5083.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://quuser:35500/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20
 * /vectornav/async_output_rate: 100
 * /vectornav/async_output_type: 0
 * /vectornav/binary_data_output_port: 2
 * /vectornav/binary_gps_data_output_rate: 4
 * /vectornav/binary_imu_data_output_rate: 100
 * /vectornav/binary_ins_data_output_rate: 20
 * /vectornav/gps/frame_id: LLA
 * /vectornav/imu/frame_id: LLA
 * /vectornav/serial_baud: 115200
 * /vectornav/serial_port: /dev/ttyTHs0

NODES
  /
    vectornav (vectornav/vn200_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found


   ERROR: cannot launch node of type [vectornav/vn200_node]: vectornav
    ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
    ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
    ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks**
No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

As you see, I got an error at last couple of lines.
Could you please let me know how i can overcome this error.

Thanks,

---

Edit:
Launch file content:

```
<launch>

    <node pkg="vectornav" type="vn200_node" name="vectornav"  output="screen" > 
      
      <param name="serial_port" type="string" value="/dev/ttyTHS0" />
      <param name="serial_baud" type="int"    value="115200" />
      
      <param name="binary_data_output_port" type="int"    value="2" />
      <param name="binary_gps_data_output_rate" type="int"    value="4" />
      <param name="binary_ins_data_output_rate" type="int"    value="20" />
      <param name="binary_imu_data_output_rate" type="int"    value="100" />
      
      <!-- Type: 0 None (Polling method), 19 IMU, 20 GPS, 22 INS -->
      <param name="async_output_type" type="int"    value="0" />
      <param name="async_output_rate" type="int"    value="100" />
      
      <param name="imu/frame_id" type="string" value="LLA" />
      <param name="gps/frame_id" type="string" value="LLA" />
    </node> 
    
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243177/%5Bvn200.launch%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package/) by [sn.badnawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27908/sn.badnawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2016-09-07**:
pls put your launch file content here.

**Comment by [sn.badnawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27908/sn.badnawa/) on 2016-09-07**:
I have posted it below.

Thanks,
Salman

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-09-08**:
Any error when you compiled? If the compilation is successful, you should be able to do "roscd vectornav" without any error.

**Comment by [sn.badnawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27908/sn.badnawa/) on 2016-09-09**:
I get the following error when doing `"roscd vectornav"`

```
roscd: No such package/stack 'vectornav'
```

**Comment by [wathab](https://answers.ros.org/users/57014/wathab/) on 2020-08-01**:
hello ,did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go to directory `YOUR_CATKIN_WORKSPACE/devel/lib`, and see if there is a folder `vectornav`. If so, see if there is a executable `vn200_node` in `vectornav`.

And also, you should setup the workspace environment, `source YOUR_CATKIN_WORKSPACE/devel/setup.bash` from your terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sn.badnawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27908/sn.badnawa/) on 2016-09-09**:
Hi Shay,
Yes there is an executable vn200_node in vectornav. Apparently I had to source the setup.bash : ) you are correct.